# Properly formatting output of arraylist data?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method in my switch statement explaining to print my arraylist
(i.e - System.out.println(drinkList);)

```
           ArrayList<String> drinkList = new ArrayList<String>();
           System.out.print("Please enter a drink information to add:\n");
           inputInfo = scan.nextLine().trim();
           drinkLink = DrinkParser.parseStringToDrink(inputInfo);
           drinkList.add(drinkLink.toString()); //Take in user data to parse into parts
```

Then I called it using the code 
               System.out.println(drinkList);

My problem is the output prints the following as such:

```
[

Data Entry 1

,

Data Entry 2

]
```

I want to remove the brackets and the comma.

Comment: Show us what your method contains then

Comment: I'll add basic code to my OP. It's a lot of code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call the `toString()` method on the ArrayList but loop through it and build a string yourself. Do something like:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String value : drinkList) {
    builder.append(value) + ",";
}
String text = builder.toString();
System.out.println(text);
```

That'll make sure that the resulting string has the format that you want - in this case comma-separated entries.

Comment: The builder.append is giving me an error, not letting me compile.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to remove the brackets and the commas:

```
String s = "[\nData Entry 1\n,\n Data Entry 2\n]";
String result = s.replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z\n]", "");
System.out.println(result);
```

The result is:

```
Data Entry 1

Data Entry 2
```

Or, you can override toString() method for **your** class.